# (phpmyadmin) how do I change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] for remote server?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php-5.3

I think phpmyadmin `index.php` is called `config.inc.php` when executed.

So I tried in `config.inc.php`

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $_GET['test']; // I changed here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
```

and call url like this.

```
http://localhost/index.php?test=211.212.14.11
```

but I got display host error and not working.
how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using GET here, which is sanitized by phpMyAdmin, the proper syntax is to put the IP address or hostname directly in for the directive, such as `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.5.6';` or `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'db.example.com';`

If you want to be able to define an arbitrary host at login time, look in to the [`$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_AllowArbitraryServer) directive (when set to true, you can enter any server on the logon page).